# Can "relevant to" be replaced by "due to"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

In the following sentence, can "relevant to" be replaced by "due to"?

> Our modification addresses the problem *relevant to* disturbing objects attached to the main object.

> Our modification addresses the problem *due to* disturbing objects attached to the main object.

Are both the sentences grammatically meaningful?

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid sentences, but they mean different things.

> Our modification addresses the problem *relevant to* disturbing objects attached to the main object.

When something is *relevant to* something else, it means that one thing relates to another and has significance in regard to it. See this [definition of relevant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/relevant):

> relevant: Having a bearing on or connection with the matter at hand

So if you use this sentence, what you're saying is that the problem is *related to* the objects in some way.

---

> Our modification addresses the problem *due to* disturbing objects attached to the main object.

*Due to* implies cause and effect; that is, the problem exists *because of* the objects attached to the main object.  So in this case the problem wouldn't exist otherwise.  You're making a direct correlation between the two; you're explaining what the cause of the problem you fixed was.  I'm guessing this is probably what you mean to say.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically meaningful, yes.

What you actually want to say, almost certainly no.

In your current construction, you have three things:

- an action (objects attached to the main object are being disturbed)
- a problem (not specified) that is either:

  - related to the disturbance, or
  - caused by the disturbance
- a modification that addresses the problem.

Reading it over, I think that what you intend is to have only two things:

- a problem (objects attached to the main object are being disturbed)
- a modification that addresses the problem.

I will guess that what you really mean in the situation is

> Our modification addresses the problem where objects that are attached to the main object are disturbed.

As in, the action is: the main object is moved.  The problem is: objects attached to the main object shift position relative to the main object as a result of the move.  The modification fixes the "move" action so that attached objects remain in the same position relative to the main object.

I'm reading a lot into this, so feel free to give additional context if I've got something wrong about the situation.